# yii2 kartik-v/yii2-widgets installation

Tags: widget, yii-extensions, yii2

I'd like  to use kartik sidenav widget. 
I installed kartik-v/yii2-widgets extension via composer.

I can see it here: advanced\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-widget-sidenav and extensions.php has also been modified:

```
 'kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav' => 
  array (
 'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav',
 'version' => '9999999-dev',
 'alias' => 
  array (
   '@kartik/sidenav' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav',
 ),
 ),
```

However, when I try to use it in my view,

```
use kartik\widgets\SideNav;

echo SideNav::widget([ 
....
```

It shows Class 'kartik\widgets\SideNav' not found error
What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

becuase author not update documentation, namespace become kartik\sidenav\SideNav,and you should use this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `kartik\sidenav\SideNav` namespace, i recommend to use an IDE like [JetBrains PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) since it will auto detect the namespaces and add them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it should be use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually:

1) Download archive of needed version from Github.

2) Find PSR-4 autoload section and remember it, in your case: `kartik/sidenav.`

3) Extract files to corresponding folder in vendor: `vendor/kartik/sidenav` (not yiisoft!).

4) Add to `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php:`

```
'kartik\\sidenav\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik/sidenav'),
```

5) Add to `vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php:`

```
'kartik/sidenav' => array (
    'name' => 'kartik/sidenav',
    'version' => '2',
    'alias' => array (
        '@kartik/sidenav' => $vendorDir . '/kartik/sidenav',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

docs have not yet been updated -

```
use kartik/sidenav/SideNav;
```

same conventions apply for all other kartik widgets e.g

```
use kartik\widgets\TypeaheadBasic
```

is now:

```
use kartik\typeahead\TypeaheadBasic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav' => array(
    'name' => 'kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav',
    'version' => '1.0.0.0',
    'alias' => array(
        '@kartik/sidenav' => $vendorDir . '/kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav',
    ),
),
```

If you installed it correctly, in the yii2 extension, it looks like the code above，So I think it is your installation error，install agin!

Answer (score 0):

1. go to vendor folder , find where your installed extensions placed and open that folder.
2. read README file.. for every extension there is README.md file and it contain a example and teach u how to use NAMESPACE.

and there is where you will find the correct NAMESPACE.